# How to specify equation for regression line in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a scatterplot in ggplot2 with one or more lines over-layed. Having looked at the documentation for geom_smooth() and geom_line(), it remains unclear to me how I can specify the equations for lines that I want to add to a plot. I understand that this must be very basic, so please feel free simply to point me toward the appropriate documentation that I must have overlooked.

Comment: `geom_abline()`, e.g. `geom_abline(aes(intercept=a,slope=b))` ... see `?geom_abline`

Comment: The documentation seems to provide some examples: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/geom_smooth.html

Comment: @BenBolker: Make that a solution and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`geom_abline()` is the name of the geom you're looking for, e.g. `geom_abline(aes(intercept=a,slope=b))`.  There are examples in [the online documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_abline.html).