# How to add regression equation to scatterplot in r

Tags: r, plot, lm

I am trying to make a basic scatterplot that displays the regression equation and r2 values in the top left of the plot panel. Below is the code to generate an initial figure with just the r2 value.

```
plot(OverlapInner$PR1Max, OverlapInner$PR4Max, ylim = c(23, 29), xlim = c(23, 29))
abline(a = 0, b = 1)
fit <- lm(PR1Max ~ PR4Max, data = OverlapInner)
legend("topleft", bty = "n", legend = paste("R2:",format(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, 
digits=4)))
```

Comment: The `abline` function recognizes `lm` objects and can add them for you, try `abline(fit)`

Comment: Excellent, but how do paste the equation as text on the figure?

Comment: I marked as duplicate because there are a few questions around getting at what you're after... hopefully the wisdom of the ancients can help. if after searching around for a bit, you're still stuck, please open a new question and there you'll be able to be more specific about what remaining issues you have :)

Comment: I agree this is duplicate but the suggested question doesn't provide the answer. The answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173468/r-print-equation-of-linear-regression-on-the-plot-itself